# fetching multiple values from the table

Tags: android

```
public List<String> getDays(long iid)
{
  List<String> days= new ArrayList<String>();
  cursor = database.query(MySqliteHelper.TABLE_REPEAT, daysColumn, MySqliteHelper.COLUMN_TID + "=" + iid, null, null, null, null);
  while(fg>=1)
  {
      cursor = database.query(MySqliteHelper.TABLE_REPEAT, daysColumn, MySqliteHelper.COLUMN_TID + "=" + iid, null, null, null, null);
          String day = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(MySqliteHelper.COLUMN_DAYS));
        days.add(day);
      cursor.moveToNext();
          if(cursor.isAfterLast())
          {
       fg=0;
          }
  }
  cursor.close();
  fg=1;
  return days;
  }
```

now I get the `arrayindexoutofbound` exception!! I'm new to android and programming.. 
suggest me what techniques I should use.

and my log cat shows:
03-06 11:20:12.941: E/AndroidRuntime(2025): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
03-06 11:20:12.941: E/AndroidRuntime(2025): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.habitator/com.example.habitator.AlarmDays}: android.database.CursorIndexOutOfBoundsException: Index -1 requested, with a size of 1

Comment: Dear, do you know exactly what is `Cursor`? And what are you doing with above code?

Comment: I have edited my question. pls do check

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why are you again query the database? and use break if cursor.isAfterLast() satisfies. because of this one, you are getting error arrayindexoutofbound and

also specify cursor.moveToFirst(); to move cursor at first position

Try this one:

```
public List<String> getDays(long iid)
{
  List<String> days= new ArrayList<String>();
  cursor = database.query(MySqliteHelper.TABLE_REPEAT, daysColumn, MySqliteHelper.COLUMN_TID + "=" + iid, null, null, null, null);
  cursor.moveToFirst();
  while(fg>=1)
  {
         if(cursor.isAfterLast())
          {
              fg=0;
              break; //brek the loop 
          }
      String day = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(MySqliteHelper.COLUMN_DAYS));
        days.add(day);
      cursor.moveToNext();  
  }
  cursor.close();
  fg=1;
  return days;
  }
```

Hope this will work for you!

Comment: I have edited my code. As you are getting -1 index, fir of all, check in you look whether cursor.isAfterLast() and if so, break the loop and if not, then only execute next code

Comment: my program doesn't crash now but displays only one row. Actually there are mane row withe constraint!! I really couldn figure why it couldn't add!!

Comment: have you removed database.query() code from your while loop?

You have written it twice and it is initializing same cursor again.

No need to write it in while loop.

please have a look at code for reference and let me know whether its working or not

Comment: sorry,, I'm new to StackExchange and don ve enough reputation to vote :( but will sure if I get enough reputation to vote :)

Answer (score 0):

```
      Cursor c=db.rawQuery("select * from table_name where user_fk='" + get_userid + "'",null);
     List<String[]> list = new ArrayList<String[]>();

         c.moveToFirst();
         while(!c.isAfterLast())
         {
             title=new String[]{c.getString(3),c.getString(0)};
             list.add(title);
             c.moveToNext(); 
         }      

     c.close();
     db.close();
```

1.use array to get the multiple value from the table.

2.After that store that array value in list.